# How to show two table in single view?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In asp.net core MVC I need to show two tables in a single view. I have one page and there is a submit button on click of that it will go to another view .there in need to show two tables. I want to use JSON. but from the controller, it returns view model .so how to convert view model data in JSON format to show it in an HTML table?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Viewbag into your controller to show two tables in one view.
keep this at the top of your view page

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
```

And I think then you can do this which you want.

```
@Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.something))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to return json, the usual solution is to create a `ViewModel`.

```
public class Model1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Model2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModel
{
    public Model1 Model1 { get; set; }
    public Model2 Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can return a `ViewModel` to the view.

If you need to return `Json`,please provide your `class model` and your `view code`.

Comment: i need json because i want to map those data with jquery datatable

Comment: please provide your class model and your view code